# Cell value string to Int in OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: openoffice-calc, worksheet-function

I have `"1 hour"`, `"2 hours"`, in a column in Calc, and I would like to extract the numbers only.  I've tried `VALUE(A9)`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an Excel solution but my understanding is that Calc supports most Excel functions.

If your number always appears at the beginning of a text string and is followed by at least one space, then:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1))
```

will extract the value from such a string in cell A1.

Comment: `=VALUE(LEFT(A1;SEARCH(" ";A1)-1))` +1.