# Strip text from number in Libre Office Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

[image]

I want to convert the string in column C into number. I want to convert "11,00 TL" to 11. How can do this?

Comment: Related question: [Cell value string to Int in OpenOffice Calc?](http://superuser.com/questions/315087/cell-value-string-to-int-in-openoffice-calc)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`SUBSTITUTE`](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUBSTITUTE_function). Enter the formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C656; "TL"; "")
```

This will give you a cell with just `11,00`.

If you use `,` as the decimal separator (in your language settings), Calc should accept `11,00` as a number, meaning you can calculate with it. If you use `.` as the decimal separator, you'll need a second step to replace , with . (also using `SUBSTITUTE`).

Another option would be to use `MID()` to trim off the last part of the text.

Also, if the data is imported from some text file, you can also use the configurable text import to import "11,0 TL" as two cells, which would also fix the problem. Depends on where you get the data from...